# Cognos Checkbox + Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cognos

Here is what I am trying to do

I have a report that looks like this

id name address
id name address

What I would like to do is add a checkbox at the end of each line like so

id name address checkbox
id name address checkbox

What I would like to do is when the user hits the checkbox and hits submit, it will put the id_number into an oracle stored procedure like so

examplestoredprocedure(id_number||,||id_number)

or something similar.

has anyone done anything like this?  We have links the user hits and it hits a stored procedure but not with multi values.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using javascript to call to the stored procedure, or are you using something integrated in Cognos, such as here http://cognosknowhow.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-allow-user-to-add-comments-using.html

Comment: @APierre can you see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can do these:

- **define a procedure on db**

//package body on oracle in my case

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package AS


procedure my_procedure ( username in varchar2 ,p_return out sys_refcursor
) as
v_Return varchar2(4000) := null; 
begin 

 --do something
 v_Return:=username;

 open p_return FOR
  SELECT CAST(v_Return AS varchar2(4000))from dual;


end my_procedure;




   END my_package;
/
```

- **create procedure on your cognos framework**

// you should use macros like this :`# prompt('p_UserName','string' ,'temp')#`

[image]

- **create a cognos report and use javascript**//in prompt page

//define checkbox in list with js like this : `<input type="CHECKBOX" id="you can define your data item"  name="chck1"  ></input>`

//you should set your values to parameters and then click button like this:

```
<a title = 'okey'; onClick="myFunction('chck1')">your button</a>
```

//define function

```
function myFunction(chkboxName)
{

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);

  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)
 {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked)
    {
        //alert( ' index '+i +' - ' +checkboxes[i].id  );
        var form = getFormWarpRequest();
        var textBox = form._textEditBoxmyeditboxname;//this is important editbox name is : myeditboxname //this is standart : form._textEditBox
        { 
       textBox.value = textBox.value+checkboxes[i].id+',';//this is uses for setting parameter value , you can set your parameter 

        }
    }
}

 promptButtonFinish(); //this uses like finish prompt 
}
```

- **and finally you can set your report page put there your procedure output(:B1)**

//put this data item to your page

```
[Business Layer].[yourdataitem].[:B1]
```

this is working for me , I hope it solves your problem